# RSA encryption with key and exponent in android

Tags: android, encryption, rsa

I have a private key and exponent, i need to implement RSA encryption of string in android application.
How can i do this? Is there any default class for the RSA encryption?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RSA Encryption: Difference between Java and Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069369/rsa-encryption-difference-between-java-and-android)

Comment: But i couldn't use this PublicKey pubKey = readPublicKeyFromFile(mod, ex); what value is needed to give in mod and ex variables, are they string or int?

Comment: I don't agree @Snicolas, the most important steps are to define the character encoding, and to derive a session key session key (or, alternatively, to define a container format such as CMS). Both are not covered by that question.

Comment: Could you indicate what format the data elements are in? To encrypt with RSA you need an RSAPublicKey consisting of the modulus and the public exponent. The default class for RSA encryption is simply the Cipher class, but you may want to use bouncy castle instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void saveToFile(String fileName, BigInteger mod, BigInteger exp)
        throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
    try {
        oout.writeObject(mod);
        oout.writeObject(exp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected error", e);
    } finally {
        oout.close();
    }
}

PublicKey ReadPublicKeyFromFile(String keyFileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = RSACrypt.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(keyFileName);
    ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
            in));
    try {
        BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
        BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
        return pubKey;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
    } finally {
        oin.close();
    }
}
```

from http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1001867/java/developpement-web-java/besoin-daide-rsa/

Comment: this is for any files to encrypt, but i need to encrypt Strings such as username and password

Comment: Not really, this is to load / save a public key from file, but I don't see a direct connection with your question either.

Comment: It was an answer to the comment of the author of the question. Below his question about the method readPubklicKey

Comment: I don't think that qualifies as an answer to the question.